# My graphic card memory is higher than my RAM memory

Tags: memory, graphics

So,I got this HD4650 which is got 1gb memory, but my ram is only 512mb, another 512mb is on shipment, so will there be any problem? I'm running on the 1gb graphic and 512mb ram right now. will this damage my PC?

Answer (score 7):

System memory and graphics card memory have nothing to do with each other. It makes no difference which one is larger. Your only issue is that 512MB of system memory is awfully low by modern standards.

Comment: Are you sure that's true? Video Card is a peripheral for a CPU and it needs to be mapped on the system RAM to exchange with register values. usually video cards use around 200MB of system RAM to map video IOs.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's true. It doesn't need to be "mapped on the system RAM", nor do video cards "usually" use any system RAM at all. (Perhaps you're confusing address space with RAM?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as your not concerned about performance, there will be no problems with your computers health.

So: No it will not damage your PC.

Comment: Your first statement is irrelevant. N0N4ME is asking for clarification on how or if the graphics card's memory interacts with the system's RAM.

Comment: Okay,tq but I think you wrong on "almost all modern purposes" I can almost do anything on windows XP sp3.
I'm just scared if it will damage any hardware. Bcuz hardware=money :(

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: still wondering if the graphics card will fit into the mainboard at all, though.

Comment: given that he says hes running on it now, i'd guess yes.

Answer (score 0):

YOu lose a lot of potential performance like for CUDA since you have to load all data into graphics card from disks or network.
It would be better that you arrange 4-8GB at least to have memory run programs and not act as a buffer for video card....

Comment: This is horrible advice.  You have no idea if his system will even support that much memory.  Besides the statement is false.

Comment: 1GB card should be PCI-E and a computer with open PCI-E slot must have at least rudimental MMU to map 64bit requests of PCI-E to 4GB of 32bit address space.